# How to automatically refresh listbox when add or remove the item in WPF?

Tags: wpf, web-services

I have WPF application that uses web service (asmx). The web service uses EF to get the data from MS SQL Server.

The code looks as following:

1) WPF:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    LetterWebServiceSoapClient _client = new LetterWebServiceSoapClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Letter> _letters;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cmdGetLetters_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstLetters.ItemsSource = null;
        _letters = _client.GetAllLetters();
        lstLetters.ItemsSource = _letters;
    }

    private void cmdDeleteLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _client.DeleteLetter((Letter)lstLetters.SelectedItem);
    }

    private void cmdAddLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newLetter = new Letter
        {
            Name = "Letter3",
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Recipient = "John",
            Sender = "David",
            Content = "cccc"
        };
        _client.AddNewLetter(newLetter);
    }
}
```

2) The web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class LetterWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    LetterDbEntities _letterDbEntities = new LetterDbEntities();

    [WebMethod]
    public ObservableCollection<Letter> GetAllLetters()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Letter>(_letterDbEntities.Letters.ToList());
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void AddNewLetter(Letter newLetter)
    {
        _letterDbEntities.Letters.Add(newLetter);
        _letterDbEntities.SaveChanges();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void DeleteLetter(Letter letter)
    {
        var letterToBeDeleted = _letterDbEntities.Letters.First(l => l.Id == letter.Id);
        _letterDbEntities.Letters.Remove(letterToBeDeleted);
        _letterDbEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I add new letter or remove existing one they are added or removed on database level, but it doesn't reflect in UI that is in list box. What I'm missing?

Comment: because your object `_letters` not changing at all during add or delete operations?

Comment: Why? The _letters is ObservableCollection type. Isn't it enough to automatically update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `_letters` collection. Try this:

```
private void cmdDeleteLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (Letter)lstLetters.SelectedItem;
    _client.DeleteLetter(selectedItem);
    _letters.Remove(selectedItem);
}

private void cmdAddLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newLetter = new Letter
    {
        Name = "Letter3",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Recipient = "John",
        Sender = "David",
        Content = "cccc"
    };
    _client.AddNewLetter(newLetter);
    _letters.Add(newLetter);
}
```

Comment: The _letters is ObservableCollection type. Isn't it enough to automatically update?

Comment: It certainly will update UI if you change _letters collection. But you don't.